# Missing or invalid 'entry.level'" error in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning Selenium Webdriver. I was trying to login "Quora" through Google. but in the email typing section, the code is not working. I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Please help. Below is my code:

```
import org.openqa.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Demo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        String url="https://quora.com";

        driver.get(url);

        WebElement ele1=driver.findElement(By.className("google_button_text"));

        ele1.click();       

        WebElement email1=driver.findElement(By.name("identifier"));

        email1.sendKeys("fggffgfd"); 

        WebElement next1=driver.findElement(By.className("RveJvd snByac")); 

        next1.click();

        WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.className("whsOnd zHQkBf"));

        password.click();

        password.sendKeys("Sffgdffdf3");

        WebElement next2=driver.findElement(By.className("RveJvd snByac")); 

        next2.click();          
    }
}
```

Comment: But I tried working mentioned in that comment also..But still getting error

Comment: Same error i got .. but resolve it by updating my chrome driver to latest V3.0  and above

Answer (score 0):

Select the element using Id instead of Name. You can use

```
By.id("identifierId")
```

Instead of

```
By.name("identifier")
```

Try using `WindowHandle` like the below code snap:

```
ele1.click();

String mainWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();

for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

WebElement email1=driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
```

It will write the text in **Email** field. Then you need to capture exact selector for **Next** button like `By.cssSelector("#identifierNext > content > span")`. In this way, try to find out the `cssSelector` for **Password** field and **Next** button as well.

At the end of code, you need add the below line of code to close the 2nd window and switch to the main window:

```
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandler);
```

Hopefully, it resolves your issue.

Comment: Tried everything including xpath. Nothing is working

Comment: @SaranyaV hey bro! I've updated the answer. Please try to implement this. try to debug the code and see if it is writing or not in email field.

Comment: @SaranyaV let me know your feedback please.

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: @Ali_Azam: It worked :) I put Thread.sleep(5000); also. Thanks much for the help. :)

Comment: @SaranyaV If you get really help from it, then please accept the answer and up vote it so that others can get help from it. I will be really happy if you do that. thanks.